# search json numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Validate numbers in JavaScript - IsNumeric()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric)

I have the following (working) code that searches for the string "type 1" in my `Json`, but how can I search for a number? I am guessing that I need to change `RegExp` to Number, but I can't get it to work, it tells me that `v.properties.code` in not a function.

```
$.each(geojson.features, function (i, v) {
    if (v.properties.code.search(new RegExp(/type 1/i)) != -1) {
         Count++;
    }
});
```

Comment: What was the RegExp that didn't work? Usually `\d` should be a (single) number.

Comment: Side note: if you already have a regular expression (`/type 1/i`) calling the `RexExp` constructor to create a regular expression is just redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numbers doesn't have the search function in their prototypes, so you just need to convert it to a string, this way you ensure it will always be a string, and you won't get that error, even though you should be doing a proper check on your content

```js
$.each(geojson.features, function (i, v) {
  if (v.properties.code.toString().search(/type 1/i) !== -1) {
     Count++;
  }
});
```

or the other (less typing) way

```js
$.each(geojson.features, function (i, v) {
  if (/type 1/i.test(v.properties.code)) { // does the conversion automatically
     Count++;
  }
});
```